# Pass enum value in mapping

Tags: solidity, mapping, enum

I am trying to pass a default value in solidity but get the following error:
`"Invalid implicit conversion from enum tlb.Category to enum tlb.Category[] memory requested"`

Does anybody have an idea of how to fix this?

```
    uint256 public pageNo = 0;
    enum Category {DEFAULT, I, II, IIIA, IIIB}
    mapping(uint => TLB) public TLBs;
    
    struct TLB{
        uint flightNo;
        string flightFrom;
        string flightTo;
        uint256[3] reportDate;
        Category[] category;
        bool EtopsFlight;
        string maintCheck;
        uint licenseNo;
        uint station;
        bool CaaCertification;
        bool handlingAgent; 
        uint CertNo;
    }
    
    function addTLB(uint _flightNo, string memory _flightFrom, string memory _flightTo, uint256[3] memory _reportDate) public {
        Category _category = Category.DEFAULT;
        
        TLBs[pageNo] = TLB(_flightNo, _flightFrom, _flightTo, _reportDate, _category, false, "", 0, 0, false, false, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your struct is expecting an array of Category `Category[] category;` and you are passing just a single enum value. If you just have to pass a single value change the struct variable to `Category category;` and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass an `Enum` value of type `Category` to your `TLBs` map, so you have to declare `category` in your `struct TLB` as `Category`.

`Category[] category;`  must be as follows  `Category category;`